# Get key value from specific userID firebase recycler adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to get the key value shown as the image below. I'm using firebase recycler adapter to retrieve the data which is from the key, but right now I want to get the key value.

[image]

Right now the code I'm using the retrieve data only this .

```
 private void setFirebaseRecyclerAdapterKarangan() {
        firebaseRecyclerOptionsKarangan = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserAlphaKaranganClick>()
                .setQuery(databaseReference.child("userAlphaKaranganClick").child(userUid), UserAlphaKaranganClick.class)
                .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapterKarangan = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserAlphaKaranganClick, UserAlphaActivityLogKaranganViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptionsKarangan) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UserAlphaActivityLogKaranganViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final UserAlphaKaranganClick model) {
            //We need to convert to become string since it is from long
            holder.getTextViewClick().setText(String.valueOf(model.getClick()));
            holder.getTextViewLike().setText(String.valueOf(model.getLike()));
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UserAlphaActivityLogKaranganViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_alpha_activity_log_karangan_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new UserAlphaActivityLogKaranganViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    //Display
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapterKarangan.startListening();
    recyclerView2.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapterKarangan);
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `onBindViewHolder` method add the following:

```
String key = firebaseRecyclerAdapterKarangan.getRef(position).getKey();
```

`getKey()` will retrieve the reference of this snapshot which is in the random ID.